# firefox add-on include timbre.js

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I was trying to make an extension for firefox and I need to use timbre.js (http://mohayonao.github.io/timbre.js/), so I thought to include it in the contentScriptFile and use it in the test.js file this way:

```
exports.main = function() {
    var widget = new Widget({
        id: "widget",
        label: "Label",
        contentURL: "cat.png",
        contentScriptFile: [data.url('timbre.js'), data.url('test.js')]      
    });
```

The problem is that it won't load because of this:

> Timestamp: 16. 07. 13 12:35:33 Error: addon_name: An exception
>   occurred. NS_ERROR_FAILURE: Failure Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/content/symbiont.js", line
>   172, in _onReady
>       self._onInit();   File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/widget.js", line 803, in null
>       this._initSymbiont();   File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/content/symbiont.js", line 200,
>   in Symbiont<._onInit
>       this._initWorker({ window: this._frame.contentWindow });   File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/content/worker.js", line 510, in
>   Worker
>       this._contentWorker = WorkerSandbox(this);   File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/deprecated/traits.js", line 114,
>   in Trait
>       return self.constructor.apply(self, arguments) || self._public;   File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/content/worker.js", line
>   302, in WorkerSandbox
>       this._importScripts.apply(this, contentScriptFile);   File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/content/worker.js", line 361, in
>   _importScripts
>       load(this._sandbox, String(uri));   File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/loader/sandbox.js", line 47, in
>   load
>       return scriptLoader.loadSubScript(uri, sandbox, 'UTF-8');   File "resource://jid0-gb1orekgm6ay3hjawryzhdrneug-at-jetpack/synesthesia/data/timbre.js",
>   line 1, in null
>       (function(t){"use strict";function e(){function e(t){for(var e,i=Array(t.byteLength),s=t.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT,n=0,r=i.length;r>n;++n)e=8*(n%s),i[n]=(
>   [...]

Even tried importing it with require() but it doesn't works.
How should I import it?
Thanks Bye!

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, there is no `contentScriptFile` for [`Widget`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/widget.html). There is also a problem how you create the `Widget`. It should be something like this and you should not use the `new` keyword:

```
const widgets = require("sdk/widget");
const data = require("sdk/self").data;

var player = widgets.Widget({
  id: "widget",
  label: "Label",
  contentURL: data.url("cat.png")
});
```

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve here. If you simply want to execute a script in the page, your solution is a [`PageMod`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/page-mod.html) and not `Widget`. If you want to execute an action in your page using `timbre.js`. The solution would be to:

- Use `PageMod` for the content scripts.
- Use `Widget` for the menu.
- Use the [communication mechanism](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/guides/content-scripts/using-port.html) (`port`) between addon code and content scripts to send *messages*.

Comment: contentScriptFile is an option for Widget.